# Using KafkaSpout with storm, how to ignore old messages?

Tags: apache-storm

For debugging purposes, when I start my topology I would like to ignore any messages which were on my Kafka queue prior to the startup. I believe this can be done by setting `spoutConfig.startOffsetTime` and `spoutConfig.useStartOffsetTimeIfOffsetOutOfRange`. But I have tried setting these to every permutation of -1,-2,-3 and true/false, respectively. And my topology continues to consume from Kafka on start up. (nothing is posting new messages to Kafka).

Is there a configuration I can use to ignore old messages? To, essentially, purge the Kafka queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure Zookeeper correctly? The last offset can be stored there and `KafkaSpout` can read the last offset from Zookeeper at start-up. Have a look here for further details:

- https://storm.apache.org/documentation/storm-kafka.html
- http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/05/27/kafka-storm-integration-example-tutorial/